# Filter a list with checkboxes in Angular 6

Tags: json, angular, filter, pipe

i have an arrray of restaurants

```
 restaurants=[
{ restname: "rest1", isDelivery: true, isItalian:false, isBreakfast:true},
{ restname: "rest2", isDelivery: false, isItalian:true, isBreakfast:true},
{ restname: "rest3", isDelivery: true, isItalian:false,isBreakfast:false}]
```

and i show them with an *ngFor like :

```
 <div *ngFor="let rest of restaurants" >
 <p> {{rest.restname}} <p>
```

and also have a list of checkbox that is for the filtering of the restuarants by category :

```
 <p *ngFor="let cat of categories">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cat.checked" > {{cat.cat}}
</p>
```

.ts

```
 categories=[
{ cat: "Delivery", checked: false},
{ cat: "Italian Food", checked: false},
{ cat: "Breakfast Service", checked: false}]
```

my main question is how can make a pipe to filter the restaurants by one or many categories with the checkbox selection?

Comment: You can use reactive forms API since you are workin with angular

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function in your component to do the filtering:

```html
<div *ngFor="let rest of getFilteredRestaurants()" >
 <p> {{rest.restname}} <p>
```

```js
public getFilteredRestaurants() {
  return this.restaurants.filter(r => this.isRestaurantVisible(r));
}

private isRestaurantVisible(restaurant: Restaurant) {
  const validCategories = this.categories.filter(c => c.checked).map(c => {
    switch(c.cat) {
      case 'Delivery': return 'isDelivery';
      case 'Italian Food': return 'isItalian';
      case 'Breakfast Service': return 'isBreakfast';
      default: return null;
    }
  });

  return validCategories.some(c => restaurant[c] === true);
}
```

Note that this may cause performance problems as these calculations will be done on each change detection cycle - you may want to implement some form of caching.